# Unable to set variable for the custom library in Robotframework Python

Tags: python, robotframework, ride

RobotFramework code

```
${Result}    Personal_ID.Main    argv=g
```

Output :

```
INFO : 090319-011F  
INFO : ${Result} = None
```

For the above code `${Result}` is coming as none , Expected : ${Result} = 090319-011F.

Comment: is `Personal_ID.Main` a keyword, and does it explicitly return something? Please show the definition of this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try using keyword  `${Result}  Set Variable <value>`